# JAVA_HOME isn't being set/ saved to the path variable after the terminal instance is being closed

Tags: java, bash, macos, terminal, environment-variables

I have been using Java 1.7 until recently for my code base, and recently we have upgraded to java 8. 
When am trying to set the JAVA_HOME variable in the .bash_profile / .bashrc file as :

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_101.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

and save it and use the source .bash_profile, the java -version points to :

```
Nitin-Vegis-MacBook-Pro:/ nitinsuryavegi$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)
```

but when i quit the terminal/ close the session and recheck the java - version it points back to the old version as this :

```
Nitin-Vegis-MacBook-Pro:/ nitinsuryavegi$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_79"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

Could you help me set the JAVA_HOME path permanently so i need not run the source .bash_profile every time i log into my terminal to keep changing the java -version from 1.7 to 1.8.

Also could someone help me understand :

1. The difference between .bash_profile and .bashrc file.
2. When i check the Java Runtime Version in my System Preferences it's been pointed to 1.8

[Click here for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjyyZ.png), but when i check the java -version in the terminal it shown as :

```
java version "1.7.0_79"
```

3. What is difference between ***$JAVA_HOME*** and ***whereis java*** command ?

Comment: Which version of `Mac OS X` are you in?

Comment: mac OS Sierra Version 10.12.2 (Just upgraded two days ago).

Answer (score 5):

> JAVA_HOME isn't being set/ saved to the path variable after the terminal instance is being closed

That is correct.  In a normal shell, the changes that you make to environment variables in the shell are lost when the shell exit.  (That applies for Linux, UNIX, Mac OS and even Windows "cmd.exe".)

The normal way to deal with this on Linux, UNIX and (I guess) Mac OS is to put shell commands to set the required variables either into one of the "rc" files for the shell, or into a wrapper script that you use to run your Java app (or whatever).

---

> Could you help me set the JAVA_HOME path permanently so i need not run the source .bash_profile every time i log into my terminal to keep changing the java -version from 1.7 to 1.8.

On UNIX / Linux, one possibility would be to put global settings into `/etc/profile`.  However, I don't know if that is right for MacOS.  In your case, it could be that you are putting the settings into the wrong file, or that you are putting *the wrong settings* into the right file.

But this is what "man bash" says about shell initialization (on my Linux system):

> *When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  ...*
>
> *When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is started, bash reads and executes commands from `~/.bashrc`, if that file  exists.  This may be inhibited by using the `--norc` option.  The `--rcfile` file option will force bash to read and execute commands from file instead of `~/.bashrc`.*

---

> Also could someone help me understand: 1)  The difference between .bash_profile and .bashrc file.

See above.

---

> 2) When i check the Java Runtime Version in my System Preferences it's been pointed to 1.8, but when I run
>
> ```
> $ java -version
> ```
>
> I get this output:
>
> ```
> java version "1.7.0_79"
> ```

My guess would be that what is your shell initialization file(s) is overriding what you have set in the System Preferences.  Also, I suspect that you may have misunderstood how the shell finds commands.  As "man bash" explains, the shell will *actually* search for commands using the `$PATH` variable. That is the variable you should check to figure out why `java -version` and `whereis java` are not behaving as you expect.

You can check what the actual environment variable settings are in a shell by typing

```
$ export
```

---

> 3) What is difference between `$JAVA_HOME` and `whereis java` command ?

The first is an environment variable ... which isn't the command search path.  It is conventionally used by *third party* tools to locate the JDK / JRE.  But the JDK / JRE tools themselves ignore it!

The second is a builtin command that attempts to find a command on the shell's *real* command search path.

Answer (score 1):

> JAVA_HOME isn't being set/ saved to the path variable after the terminal instance is being closed

That is not correct. It is saved to the PATH variable as soon as you save it. However it doesn't affect currently open terminal windows, only new ones. Closing the terminal window has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It isn't saving even after i close and open a new instance of Terminal.